# Mono 4.2.2 garbage collection really slow/leaking on Linux with multiple threads?

Tags: multithreading, mono, garbage-collection

I have an app that processes 3+GB of data into 300MB of data. Run each independent dataset sequentially on the main thread, its memory usage tops out at about 3.5GB and it works fine.

If I run each dataset concurrently on 10 threads, I see the following:

- Virtual memory usage climbs steadily until allocations fail and it crashes. I can see GC is trying to run in the stack trace)
- CPU utilization is 1000% for periods, then goes down to 100% for minutes, and then cycles back up. The app is easily 10x *slower* when run with multiple threads, even though they are completely independent.

This is mono 4.2.2 build for Linux with large heap support, running on 128GB RAM with 40 logical processors. I am running mono-sgen and have tried all the custom GC settings I could think of (concurrent mark-sweep, max heap size, etc).

These problems do not happen on Windows. If I rewrite code to do significant object pooling, I get farther in the dataset before running OOM, but the fate is the same. I have verified that I have no memory leaks using multiple tools and good-old printf-debugging.

My best theory is that lots of allocations across lots of threads are a weak case for the GC, and most of that wall-clock time is spent with my work threads suspended.

Does anyone have any experience with this? Is there a way I can help the GC get out of that 100% rut it gets stuck in, and to not run out of memory?

Comment: Another informative tidbit: running the datasets sequentially in the main thread: 2 hours. Running sequentially in background threads (1 at a time): 6+ hours, much higher memory usage and time.